# Find a Customer that buys only a specific product & did not buy any other product (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Table -

| CustomerID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mobile |
| 1 | AC |
| 2 | Mobile |
| 2 | Mobile |
| 3 | Mobile |
| 3 | Fridge |

**Question** -
I need to find Customers that buy only "Mobile" product & did not buy any other product
So in case of above table, the expected answer is 2 (because Customer 1 & 3 buys AC & Fridge).

I can execute this query in MS SQL Server using "Except" function

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CustomerID) FROM Table WHERE(Product = 'Mobile')
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT(CustomerID) FROM Table WHERE(Product != 'Mobile');
```

Can anyone please provide me the correct query for MySQL as "Except" function is not available in MySQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is aggregation and `having`:

```
select customerid
from t
group by customerid
having sum(product = 'Mobile') > 0 and
       sum(product <> 'Mobile') = 0
```

Comment: if product can be null, and a null row should also exclude the customer, this would need to be `... and sum(not(product <=> 'Mobile')) = 0`

Answer (score 1):

In a table like this it's safe to assume that the column `Product` is not nullable.

By using conditional aggregation you only need to check if the customer did not buy any product other than `'Mobile'`:

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM tablename
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING SUM(Product <> 'Mobile') = 0;
```

Or, with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.CustomerID
FROM tablename t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM tablename t2 
  WHERE t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID AND t2.Product <> 'Mobile'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM Table
WHERE Product = 'Mobile'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Table T2 WHERE T2.Product != 'Mobile' AND T2.CustomerID=Table.CustomerID
)
```

or the equivalent

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table.CustomerID
FROM Table
LEFT JOIN Table T2 ON T2.CustomerID=Table.CustomerID AND T2.Product <> 'Mobile'
WHERE Table.Product = 'Mobile' AND T2.CustomerID IS NULL;
```

(If there are not a lot of rows, or a significant percentage of customers did buy Mobile, Gordon's sum approach works well.  Otherwise, joining allows use of indexes on Product and CustomerID for potentially better efficiency.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following. It eliminates the customer IDs who bought other products along with Mobile

```
select customerid,product
from table t1
where t1.product = 'Mobile'
    and not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t1.customerid = t2.customerid
    and t2.product != 'Mobile');
```